# Using External Services with an API that Returns No Body or an Object

Tags: external-services, openapispecification

I have set up an integration using External Services and this is mainly working as expected. [Here is the full schema](https://epc.opendatacommunities.org/openapi/index.html)

One of the GET requests returns an object when valid data is found (based on parameters) which works perfectly using the schema provided:

```
"application/json": {
  "schema": {
    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Certificates"
  }
}
```

However, when this GET request does not find any data, it does not return a response body at all. This seems strange, I'd expect an error or an empty object but I can't change the way this external API works. Unfortunately, Salesforce's external service code does not understand this and throws an internal error when trying from both flow and Apex:

`System.UnexpectedException: Salesforce System Error: 1471247404-27914 (-2120813567) (-2120813567)`

When I try modifying the schema to expect a string instead:

```
"application/json": {
  "schema": {
    "type": "string"
  }
}
```

this works when no data is found but errors now when data is found:

`System.CalloutException: The response body for application/json must be an object or array data type for response parameter 200, operation getDomesticSearch and service EnergyPerformanceCertificatesAPI`

I thought maybe that using the `oneOf` keyword would give me a working solution for both no response body and an object:

```
"application/json": {
  "schema": {
    "oneOf": [
      {
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Certificates"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

but this only works for when an object is returned. It still doesn't work for when no response body is returned, despite it working when just `"type": "string"` is used.

I've also tried using various combinations of `"nullable": true` but this seems to have no effect. I don't think the dynamic Apex classes generated are any different with this so perhaps Salesforce is ignoring this from the schema?

Anyone come across this before and know whether or not this is possible with External Services or am I going to have to resort to code?